# Ruby on Rails SQL "SELECT" taking a long time

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am selecting records from a table named "bookings" that contains over 100,000 records. I am new to SQL and for some reason this is taking many seconds to finish, and even timing out on my production server:

```
def bookings_in_date_range(division, startdate, enddate)
  sql = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE division = '#{division}';"
  bookings = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql) # all bookings from this division
  bookingsindaterange = bookings.select { |b| (parsedate(b["date"]) >= parsedate(startdate)) and (parsedate(b["date"]) <= parsedate(enddate)) } # refine to bookings in date range
end

def parsedate(date) # get date from mm/dd/yy format
  d = date.split("/")
  return Date.parse("#{d[2]}-#{d[0]}-#{d[1]}")
end
```

I also included the function I'm using to re-format the date, however executing the SQL statement appears to be where the process is hanging up, based on my tests.

My goal is to select all "bookings" in a "division" within a specified date range. Existing code works faster for divisions with low numbers of bookings.

**EDIT**

Otávio's code below seems to speed things up a bit. However, my requirement is to see if a booking falls within a date range (on or after startdate **and** on or before enddate). I can't figure out how to get this logic into the .where statement, so I am running a loop like this:

```
    bookings_start_thru_end = []
    (startdate..enddate).each do |date|
      date_bookings = Booking.where("division = ? AND date = ?",division, date.strftime("%m/%d/%y"))
      date_bookings.each do |b|
        bookings_start_thru_end.push b
      end
    end
```

Also, the issue with crashing was ActiveRecord session store filling up. I was dumping a bunch of data from the report into the session store to save it between requests to avoid doing another database query, but this was killing performance. The database query is still taking 5 seconds or so, but I can live with that.

Comment: how many seconds before timeout? describe server location or anything about it (GoDaddy, right next to you, etc)

Comment: It's an in-house server with more than adequate hardware, and I'm running Phusion Passenger on top of Nginx, with Sqlite for the database. As per my edit above, I resolved the timeout issue which was due to the session store, but the database request is still taking around 5 seconds, which I supposed might just be normal for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thank you for sharing about the session store

Comment: Yeah, that threw me for a loop. I thought the session store would be a good place to store data between requests, however once I dumped a few thousand lines in there, it severely degraded the performance of the entire app to nearly unusable. From what I've read, if I want to persist generated data between requests, I might have to create a model in the database and store it there.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible, you should avoid executing raw SQL in your applications. Prefer to use ActiveRecord interfaces, this not only will make your app more secure but it will also execute queries in a way in which they are optimized to.
In your case, refactor your `bookings_in_date_range` method to use ActiveRecord's `.where` method:

```
def bookings_in_date_range(division, enddate, startdate)
  YourModelName.where("division = ? AND enddate = ? AND startdate = ?",division, parsedate(enddate), parsedate(startdate))
end
```

To look for things in a range, use

```
YourModelName.where("division = ? AND enddate <= ? AND startdate >= ?",division, parsedate(enddate), parsedate(startdate))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use EXPLAIN to see what the query execution plan is:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html

Now my guess is that you do not have indexes on the columns that you are referencing in your WHERE and that leads to table scans which are causing your query to run very slowly. But that is just my guess since I do not know your tables.

The indexes will be required whether you are using raw sql or active record (spit).